# Create popup alert box for my code

Tags: javascript, html

How to show this `info()` on popup box???

The above code was generated from system build in alert box....

```js
function BuyNow(Id, Price, Qty, Paymentmode) {
  var Info = "Ticket Id: " + Id;
  Info += "\nPrice: " + Price;

  var Qty = 1;
  if ($("#Qty" + Id)) {
    Qty = parseInt($("#Qty" + Id).val());
  }

  Info += "\nQty: " + Qty +
          "\nNet Amount: " + Price.substring(0, 1) + (parseFloat(Price.substring(1).replace(/[^\d\.\-\ ]/g, '')) * Qty +
          "\npayment: " + Paymentmode);

  alert(Info);
}
```

Comment: `window.alert()` is a popup box already.. If you want to style your box, check [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

Comment: Why are you passing in Qty and then not using it? You're defining another variable called Qty inside that function. Some proper variable naming would help here too. buyNow, id, price, quantity, paymentMode, etc. Also seems to be expecting price to be a string, which is a little odd. The popup alert box works fine BTW. All you need is jQuery and to call this function, passing in the appropriate parameters (price as a string).

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it using jquery.ui modal dialog.**

First add this to your HTML:

```
 <div id="modalInfo" style="display:none">
        <label id="info" />
  </div>
```

Then in your function set the `info` label with your `Info` value and then you can display the modal.

```
$("#info").text(Info);
$("#modalInfo").dialog();
```

Don't forget to add a reference to jquery and jquery.ui (you have to download them first)

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/libs/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```